# future tense of a present tense

Tags: tenses

> My time for the marathon next year ***will*** certainly be worse than
>   it ***is*** tomorrow.
>  (The Cambridge Grammar of the English
>   Language)

Is ***is*** being present tense saying ***is*** is the same tense of future as ***will*** (simultaneity); or ***is*** is anterior to ***will***?

Comment: I don't you can use *is* there... you're talking about the future.

Comment: This is just a complicated use of [prolepsis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolepsis).

Comment: Could you give us a link for that quote? It seems weird to me, I'd say _worse than it **will** be tomorrow_. @Robusto wouldn't you?

Comment: @terdon: that term *is* linked.

Comment: @Robusto sorry, still confused. Would you actually use that form? Perhaps you could elaborate with one of your nice answers?

Comment: I'm retired. But a simple example of prolepsis would be: *If the ship doesn't get here by next Tuesday, we're all dead.* (Instead of  *we will all be dead.*)

Comment: This may not be satisfying as an answer, but in everyday usage, the reality is that you can play a little fast and loose with relative tenses when you already have explicit time markers like "next year" and "tomorrow." We know that "tomorrow" is in the future by definition, so fudging the near-future as present doesn't add any significant confusion.

Comment: You're mixing up *future tense*, which English lacks, and *future time*, which English is able to express.  One of the ways English can express future time is via *modals*, such as **will**.  That doesn't make it a tense, periphrastic or otherwise.  See CGEL, pages 105-107 and 209-210.

Comment: _Is_ and _will_ both be used to express future time, and neither is necessarily anterior to the other.

Comment: English does have a simple future tense that is formed by using modals. It will rain tomorrow. It is going to rain tomorrow.

Comment: @snailboat You are not using the word *tense* the way it is used by 99% of the texts and 99.9999617245% of the people. That is of little use when attempting to communicate.

Comment: @tchrist Maybe so, if 99.9999617245% of people discuss only traditional grammar.  But it looks to me like Listenever is interested in the analysis presented by CGEL, so I thought I'd respond in the relevant context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have had a lot of excellent explanation here, more than enough to understand how these words are doing their work. I merely want to add a direct, explicit answer to your *specific* question, which, as far as I can tell, has not yet appeared in this discussion.

You are wondering if there is a temporal connection between ***will*** and ***is*** in your original example, and the simple answer is no. The way these words are used here does not establish a time, tense, modal, nor any other relative kind of connection between them. I see that you are reading ***is*** as if it is meant to imply the events are occurring at the same time, but it puzzles you because normally ***is*** comes before ***will***.

From the answers you already have, you now can see that the timing of the events is established by "next year" and "tomorrow," so there is no question of which occurs when. You then also can see that the usual relationship between "is" and "will," in the way you are regarding their tenses (or modality), is not operative here, because "is" is being used in an unusual, but still acceptable, way. The relationship between "is" and "will" cannot, in this case, override the defining "time definition" that the reader is required to understand from "next year" and "tomorrow."

Answer (score 1):

I hate to disagree with “The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language”, but the “it” looks to me as though it refers to, not merely “my time”, but, “my time for the marathon next year”.  Thus, I would say, “that of tomorrow”… or just “tomorrow’s”.

As for loose use of tense… [not that I *actually would* do this, but] I would go for “than it *was* tomorrow”, since looking back from next year seems to fit better than viewing tomorrow as the present.  Not being dogmatic.

(It looks to me as though noone has actually explicitly answered your question (including myself), but that it is probably fairly clear now anyway.)

Comment: You can't use *was* when you are referring to something in the future like this.

Comment: Begging your pardon, but surely the same logic would apply to using “is”?

Comment: No, because "is" can be understood to mean "is going to be". Tense in speech (and often in writing) is rather fluid. However *was* is firmly rooted in the past.

Comment: My time for the marathon will certainly be worse next year than it is tomorrow.  I guess what I am trying to say is that — noting that I know rather less about English, explicitly, than others here, including you — I think it is only reasonable to use “is” to refer to something in the future _if_ it is certain.  [I am getting tired of sometimes being allowed to use CR, and sometimes not.]  My objection is to this particular sentence.  What is certain, according to the sentence, is that next year’s time will be compromised in some way.  Conversely, then, the “is” would be misused, as tomorrow’s

Comment: time will be whatever it will be, without being systematically compromised.

Answer (score 1):

The guide is giving an example of commonly used phrasing; that is, you can use "is" that way, and it has been used that way, and you will be understood. Best to avoid it in formal writing, though.

Answer (score 1):

You normally don't use *is* **by itself** for the future tense.

*Is* can be "**anterior**" to be, but **only** if it's followed by "**going to.**" You can create the [simple future tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_tense#English) with either ***be (e.g. am/is/are) going to*** or ***will.***

I think "is" is awkward in your sentence. I like to keep the subjects/verbs in a parallel structure when comparing like events. Here's what I mean:

My time for the marathon next year ***is*** *certainly* ***going to be*** worse than **it's** ***going to be*** tomorrow.

*Be* (bare infinitive) is still your main verb, not *is*.

*Will* works too though:

My time for the marathon next year will certainly be worse than it <del>***is***</del>  ***will be*** tomorrow.

You have two independent clauses that are being joined by *than* (*than* is functioning as a conjunction). I can break those clauses down like this:

My time for the marathon next year will be worse.

It (*or* My time) will be worse tomorrow.

Because the subject of both clauses is the same (*time*), and since you can use the same verb for both clauses, you can even truncate it further:

My time for the marathon next year will certainly be worse than <del>***it will be***</del> tomorrow.

**EDIT**: It's not at all incorrect. I'd be more concerned that my reader would think I made a grammatical error the way that it is constructed though. It just sounds off, which is why many, including me, misread it. Upon re-reading (several times over), it does work. I'd say that *going to* is implied whether you include it or not.

I recommend that when comparing like events, that you stay consistent with your modals. I was wrong, however, to state that ***is*** can **never** be used for the future. See below.

Comment: Certainly _is_ can have future meaning. _When is the doctor in?_ _He's in on Tuesday, Wednesday, and all next week_. I believe that it is a myth that English has a future tense: the modal _will_ often conveys future meaning, but it does not always do so, and there are other ways of conveying future meaning.

Comment: I stand corrected. I hadn't thought of it in that way. That's a slightly different situation. I suppose that what's bothering me is that will is used in the first clause and then the tense shifts during the comparison in the second clause. With the subject being the same, it seems out of place. I'll fix my answer though.

Comment: Two independent clauses? I don’t think so. “My time will be worse tomorrow.”? Definitely not. “It [my time] will be tomorrow” is short for “***what*** my time will be tomorrow.” This is a dependent clause, like “that ate my homework” in the context, “Fido is the dog that ate my homework” (in contrast to “The dog ate my homework.”)

Comment: ***My time for the marathon next year will be worse** than **it is in tomorrow's marathon***  *What my time will be tomorrow* is fine if you prefer, but since *what* is a pronoun, *what my time will be tomorrow* is the subject (and incidentally, is conveniently synonymous with my original *my time/it*). It's a noun clause. And it can be written as two separate sentences.